# Jenkins Pipeline Compiler-Warnings plugin declaration

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know how to correctly declare the Compiler-Warnings plugin in a pipeline? I'm trying to set it up for PMD, SpotBugs, Checkstyle, and Jacoco.

I've tried the following but only received a "No warning parsers defined" error.

`warnings canRunOnFailed:true`

#### No warning parsers defined Stacktrace

```
java.io.IOException: Error: No warning parsers defined in the job configuration.
at hudson.plugins.warnings.WarningsPublisher.perform(WarningsPublisher.java:308)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwarePublisher.perform(HealthAwarePublisher.java:69)
at hudson.plugins.analysis.core.HealthAwareRecorder.perform(HealthAwareRecorder.java:298)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

#### Resources

- https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.MavenPublisherContext.warnings
- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings/
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/warnings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635813/warningsplugin-not-collecting-warnings-from-msbuild